# Dropwizard validation not working

Tags: validation, dropwizard

Environment: Dropwizard 0.8.1, Java 1.8

I can't get Dropwizard's validation support to do anything. I believe I'm following what the manual suggests. Using the following resource, for example (and variants using @Valid on the model class attributes, @Validated instead of @Valid, hibernate's @NotEmpty instead of javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, etc):

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource {
    static public class ModelClass {
        @JsonProperty("only_null") @Null public String onlyNull;
        @JsonProperty("not_null") @NotNull public String notNull;
    }

    @PUT
    public ModelClass testContainer(@Valid ModelClass record) {
        return record;
    }
}
```

If I PUT the following:

```
{"only_null":"shouldFail"}
```

rather than the expected 422, I get back:

```
{"only_null":"shouldFail","not_null":null}
```

What am I missing here? Is there some configuration that needs to be turned on to enable the validation that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.  I used the following annotations:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Null;
```

Double check how you are sending the request.  I used `curl` to send the requests:

```
$ curl -v -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080/test' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"only_null":"shouldFail"}'
< HTTP/1.1 422
{"errors":["notNull may not be null (was null)","onlyNull must be null (was shouldFail)"]}
```